# Are elementary embeddings of an inner model in itself possible?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

By Kunen's inconsistency in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ there is no nontrivial elementary embedding $j\colon V\prec V$.

Is it possible to have an inner model $M$ (a transitive class containing all ordinals of $V$) of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with a nontrivial elementary embedding $M\prec M$? In particular can there be a nontrivial elementary embedding $L\prec L$? Can such an embedding be definable? What are good sources to read about this kind of questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. That is the idea of sharps.

Specifically, $0^\#$ is equivalent to (and sometimes defined as) the statement that there is $j\colon L\prec L$. By Kunen's theorem it is impossible that $0^\#$ is in $L$ itself, but that's okay. We don't mind.

If there is a measurable cardinal, $0^\#$ exists. And $0^\#$ cannot be produced by set forcing.

Jech has a lot about it, Kanamori too. Schindler's book might contain condensed information on the topic as well.

Comment: Aha, interesting, I've only heard the name $0^\#$ before, but never really looked into it, time to go back to Kanamori and find out what this is all about!

Comment: (also do you get a notification on your phone or something when a set theory question is asked? I'm starting to bet on how many minute it'll take you to answer every time I post a question :P)

Comment: Is the argument to go from a measurable $\kappa$ to an embedding $L\prec L$ just "take $j\colon V\prec M$ witnessing the measurability of $\kappa$ and look at $j\upharpoonright L$?" Since "$x\in L$" can be written in the $\in$-language we have $j(x)\in L$ for all $x\in L$ and the restriction should still be elementary

Comment: Yes, that is the argument.

Comment: You can extend it to any inner model of the form $L(x)$ where $j(x)=x$. So for example any $x$ whose rank is below the critical point of an embedding (i.e. below a measurable).

Comment: I see, thanks! What about elementary embeddings $\mathsf{HOD}\to\mathsf{HOD}$? Can those exist? More generally is there a "reasonable" inner model $M$ in which Kunen's inconsistency goes through and so there can be no nontrivial elementary embeddings $M\prec M$?

Comment: Ah, well. Now it gets tricky. Go read about Woodin's HOD Conjecture!

Comment: Do you have a good source to read about it? My google fu is failing...

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00613

Comment: Thanks, I'll need some time to digest this but I'm going to read it!